# Reading certain column only if certain value remain the same in c++

Tags: c++, file-io

I am trying to create objects from a data file that contain data from certain columns only if the mass, which is the first column, stay the same. This is my attempt for now -

```
void read_mass() {
        vector<double> value(29);
        double _value ;
        double _mass ;
        double _next_mass ;
        _file >> _mass ;
        WimpData* mDM = new WimpData(_mass) ;
        _next_mass = _mass ;
        cout << "Reading data for mass " << _mass << endl;
        do {
            for (int i=0 ; i < 29 ; i++) {
                _file >> _value ;
                value[i]=_value;
                cout << value[i] << " ";
            }
            mDM->add_line(value[0] ,value[23],value[24],value[25]);
            if (_file.eof()) break ;
            _file >> _next_mass ;
        } while (_next_mass == _mass) ;
        _wimp.insert(pair<double, WimpData*>(_mass, mDM));
        cout << "Finished reading data for mass " << _mass << endl ;

    }
```

The first time that I use this function it works as it should. In the second call I see that  the pointer for the file has not stayed at the location where the mass has a new value, but stepped only one step.

How can I do such that the pointer of the file will keep counting inside the do-while loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you readed the _next_mass and in the next execution you're starting from reading the first value to _mass (you readed it in execution before).

For example you can do class for reading it and keep the last readed mass in private variable.  And add any function init() which will read the initial mass.

The fast solution:

```
double _mass = -1.0; //initial mass firstly not read (-1)
void read_mass() {
    vector<double> value(29);
    double _value ;
    double _next_mass ;
    if(_mass == -1)
        _file >> _mass ;
    WimpData* mDM = new WimpData(_mass) ;
    _next_mass = _mass ;
    cout << "Reading data for mass " << _mass << endl;
    do {
        for (int i=0 ; i < 29 ; i++) {
            _file >> _value ;
            value[i]=_value;
            cout << value[i] << " ";
        }
        mDM->add_line(value[0] ,value[23],value[24],value[25]);
        if (_file.eof()) break ;
        _file >> _next_mass ;
    } while (_next_mass == _mass) ;
    _wimp.insert(pair<double, WimpData*>(_mass, mDM));
    cout << "Finished reading data for mass " << _mass << endl ;


    _mass = _next_mass; //we readed the first mass of next line (save it)
}
```

Comment: Cool! You got it right, I haven't noticed that one, now it works as it should.

Comment: @OmerTzuk You should up vote the answers that helped you, and click on the checkbox near the answer that solved your problem. By doing these things you are helping future visitors like yourself.